# Ignore not-passed args

Tags: python, file, arguments, argparse

I am trying to generate some JSONs based on passed arguments, but everytime I run the script it generates all JSONs, not only those I specify in the CLI

```
import json
import argparse
listOfJSONS = {
    "JSON1" : "path",
    "JSON2" : "path",
    ...
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser.add_argument(
            "--JSON1",
            action='store_true',
            default=False,
            help="Creates one JSON",
        )

    parser.add_argument(
            "--JSON2",
            action='store_true',
            default=False,
            help="Creates different JSON",
        )
    # repeat .add_argument() for all JSONS in the dict
    args = parser.parse_args()
        for arg in vars(args):
            if arg in listOfJSONS .keys():
                with open(listOfJSONS.get(arg), "w", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
                json_file.write(json_string)
```

But when I run

```
python ./JSONgenerator.py --JSON1 --JSON2
```

It creates all JSONs specified in the listOfJSONS, not only the two I specified.
Thank you very much for any help

EDIT: I also tried to use `sys.argv([1:])` in `args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])` with no success

Comment: `for arg in vars(args): if arg in listOfJSONS .keys():` doesn't look like it does what you think it does, but I'm not too familiar with argparse. Try adding some print statements to check what vars(args) is.

Comment: Argparse will always return all defined args, they will just have true or false values depending on the command line args. You're just never checking whether they're true or false…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for arg, argbool in args._get_kwargs():
    if argbool and arg in listOfJSONS.keys():
        with open(listOfJSONS.get(arg), "w", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
            json_file.write(json_string)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you could simplify this quite a bit by just using one argument with `nargs`. Here is an example:

```py
import argparse

JSON_PATHS = {
    "JSON1": "path/json1",
    "JSON2": "path/json2",
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("files", nargs="+")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    for f in args.files:
        print(JSON_PATHS.get(f))
```

```
➜ ./main.py JSON1 JSON2
```

outputs:

```
path/json1
path/json2
```